# Power series question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left({-2 \over D } \right)^k \left[\frac{\Pi_{i=1}^{k}(2i-1+ \lambda) }{(2k)!}x^{2k}\right]$$
Provided that for $k=0$ the series is $1$.

What function hold this kind of series? Is this a cosine series? if YES then what is the final answer in term of cosine function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you will like it ! The result of your summation is
-1 + Hypergeometric1F1[(1 + lambda)/2, 1/2, -(x^2/D)].

Comment: Can you please write down that one using LaTex format. Thanks

Comment: @Malik. I am almost blind and I have a lot of problems using LaTex. Sorry for that.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the help. 
I want to ask one more thing that is it possible to put that in a solution of differential equation to find the constants by using conditions?

Comment: @Malik. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_series#The_series_1F1

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_series#The_series_1F1.
You will find the differential equation it corresponds to.

Comment: can you please help me for this
 $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left({-2 \over D } \right)^k \left[\frac{\Pi_{i=1}^{k}(2i+ \lambda) }{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}\right]$$

Comment: @Malik. I posted an anwer (I refer to it speaking about the new summation).

Comment: is this one is right? Thanks
Z^(1/2) Hypergeometric1F1[(2 + lambda)/2, 3/2, -(x^2/D)].

Comment: @Malik. What is Z^(1/2) ?

Comment: sorry it is x not z.

Answer (score 0):

@Malik. Interesting enough, each term of the new summation has a closed form which is

(2^(2 k) (-(1/D))^k x^(1 + 2 k) Pochhammer[1 + lambda/2, k])/(1 + 2 k)!

The result of the new summation is

x (-1 + Hypergeometric1F1[1 + lambda/2, 3/2, -(x^2/D)])

Thanks for having accepted my answer.

Comment: I have not understand that why we have '-1' in the start of both series? also for k=3 the hyper geometric series does not have the same answer as the original series have. why is it so?

Comment: Actually, I have got these two series by solving an ODE. Now how can I apply boundary conditions on these series? I have to find lambda some how. If you have some idea i will be very thankful to you.

Comment: @Malik. Taking into account what you have now, how do write the boundary conditions ? Let us see what we could do.

Comment: This is the equation for which you helped me a lot. Thanks for the help and concern. 
$$y(x)=b_0\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left({-2 \over D } \right)^k \left[\frac{\Pi_{i=1}^{k}(2i-1+ \lambda) }{(2k)!}x^{2k}\right]+b_1\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left({-2 \over D } \right)^k \left[\frac{\Pi_{i=1}^{k}(2i+ \lambda) }{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}\right]$$

Conditions are: $y(a)=0$ and $y(-\infty)=0$.
where $b_0$ and $b_1$ are constants.

Comment: Can we represent these Confluent Hypergeometric Functions in terms of Hermite Functions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Relation_to_confluent_hypergeometric_functions

Comment: But how in this case?